Proving an inequality on a monotonic sequence of positive real numbers
For a natural number $M > 1$, define a real number $p$ as:
$$
p = \frac{1 - e^{-Mz_M}}{\sum_{i=1}^{M} e^{-iz_i}}
$$
Case 1
For the sequence $\langle z_i \rangle$ satisfying
$$
0 < z_1 < \ldots < z_M
$$
Prove that $z_M > p$
Case 2
For the sequence $\langle z_i \rangle$ satisfying
$$
0 < z_M < \ldots < z_1
$$
Prove that $z_M < p$
My attempt
I define
$$
S = p \cdot \sum_{i=1}^{M} e^{-iz_i} - z_M
$$
I now try to prove $z_M < 0$ or $z_M > 0$ depending upon which case I am handling.
To do so, I try to bound the term $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{M} e^{-iz_i}$ using the given inequalities, for example, in Case 1, $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{M} e^{-iz_i} > M e^{-Mz_M}$ or using $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{M} e^{-iz_i} < M$ to eliminate terms except those containing $M$ and $z_M$ and then try to use derivatives and monotonicity to prove that the resulting expressions satisfy the given inequalities.
However, I have not been able to make any progress on either of the cases. I have a feeling like both of these questions are connected, so somehow cracking one of the cases should make the other case trivial. Is my intuition and approach correct? How do I prove these inequalities?

Unless I am mistaken, the first inequality is wrong for $(z_1, z_2, z_3) = (1.0, 1.1, 1.2)$. I get $p \approx 1.922$ which is larger than $z_3$.

You are right! I got this question in a book, and it seems like one of the claims is indeed incorrect. Thanks for pointing it out.

Case 1. Let $q=e^{-z_M}.$ Then $$\sum_{i=1}^Me^{-iz_i}>\sum_{i=1}^Mq^i={q(1-q^M)\over 1-q}$$ Therefore $$ p={1-q^M\over \sum_{i=1}^Me^{-iz_i}}<{1-q\over q}=e^{z_M}-1$$ When $z_i\nearrow z_M$ we get equalities, hence $p=e^{z_M}-1.$ Therefore the only inequality we may expect is $z_M>\log (p+1).$
Case 2. Applying the same procedure we get $p>e^{z_M}-1.$ As $e^{z_M}-1> z_M$ then $p>z_M.$
